# Skeletoning Windows XP or 7 for "fake Mac OS X" virtualization

Tags: windows, macos, vmware, virtualization

Having virtualized the Mac OS X 10.7 Lion with VMware Workstation i want to start with iOS development and it works.

However I want to achieve better performance to run the Mac OS as a "primary OS" on my laptop.

What I was thinking about is to set up Windows to kill all processes on startup which do not need to be executed (Sound, Aero, Explorer, ...) and to execute VMware automatically so that it seems we're are directly booting into Mac OS X without too many unnecessary services running in the background.

This would be the only solution I can think about due to the restriction that it is VERY difficult to run Mac OS X natively on a laptop or PC. Any idea how I can manage this or do you even know any better solutions to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 2):

> do you even know any better solutions to achieve what i want?

### [Buy a Mac!](http://store.apple.com/)

Bonus: You'll be in compliance with the Mac OS X License Agreement, which requires that you only install the operating system on official Apple-branded hardware. Installation on a virtual machine is explicitly forbidden, and quite unlikely to be successful for an iOS developer.

You'll also need to buy an iPhone or iPad anyway to test your applications on the physical hardware.